# How to know if a bootstrap modal was hidden by a button or programatically

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using **twitter bootstrap** and would like to know if there is a way for me to know how the modal that is currently visible was hidden.

What happens is that once a user leaves the modal (Clicks the black background or dismissing it via button) after changing something within in, another **modal pops up** and asks him if he's sure.

This is all well but the problem occurs when the same thing happens after I programmatically hide a modal like:

```
$("#modalName").modal('hide');
```

Is there a way for me to know how exactly the modal was hidden?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

**Andre:** I'm trying to go to your second solution but I get some weird reaction

I changed the bootstrap hide function to include another parameter:

```
hide: function (e, programatically) {
  alert(e);
  alert(programatically);
  if (programatically)
    alert('should be seen only from code');
```

And when I call from the API I use this:

```
$("#modalName").modal("hide", true)
```

What strangely happens is that the alert on 'e' shows me the 'true' value and the alert on 'programatically' shows me undefiend. Also, when calling like this the modal doesn't get hidden and I get this error:

```
TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'preventDefault'
```

Comment: this additional modal popup is from twitter bootstrap??

Comment: Yes André, it is a modal over modal using bootstrap.

Comment: how do you set it to show when you dismiss first popup?

Comment: In my case I don't dismiss the first popup when showing the second one. It just goes above him. That specific aspect of what I'm trying to achieve actually works good. The problem is that the whole process happens even when I hide modals progrematically, which is something I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using **[`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target)** .

Something similar to this

```
document.onclick = function (e) {
    var tar = e.target;
    var elementTag = $(tar).get(0).tagName;
    if (elementTag == "BUTTON") {
        alert("button clicked");
    } else {
        alert("others");
    }
}
```

You can try changing to class name/id(if any).

Hope you can understand.

Comment: Thanks user1671639, I did try that but for me, elementTag is always DIV so I get the "others" alert all the time.

Comment: @RonH Yes it will be, because you're using bootstrap.  In bootstrap, the div is decorated as a button, model, or etc.,  That why I mentioned to get the class name or id.  Let me try to add some examples.

Comment: I'm hoping from something that does not include adding class names and getting the info straight from the e object. Although, if everything else fails I might have no choice :)

Comment: @RonH I remember that bootstrap button used to have a class like `btn`.  You can use it `var elementClass = $(tar).get(0).className;` and change you if statement to `if (elementClass == "btn") {
        alert("button clicked");
    }`

Comment: I understand. However, I'm trying to get the information from binding the 'hide' method to the pop up. This means that the target for me will always be the DIV that is the container of the pop up. So unfortunately I don't think I can use this

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you are using jQuery, you can use event.target: (IE window.event use event.srcElement):

   ```
   $(submitButton).click(function(e) {
       alert(e.target.src);
   });
   ```
2. Add a parameter like `programatically`.. and set it to show additional popup only when it called not via programtically:

   ```
   hide: function ( e, programatically ) {
       [...]
       if (!programatically){
            // Show additional confirm popup
       }
       [...]
   }
   ```

and call when hiding progamatically:
       $("#modalName").modal('hide', true);

Comment: I tryed using your second solution and I get some weird behavior. I explained it in details in my original post above

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to hide the bootstrap modal.

```
 $("#modalName").hide();
 $(".modal-backdrop").hide();
```